# TYPO3 v9 Routing: How to make a part of the routePath respect the resolved value of another part?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have an extbase extension with two models which have a 1:n relation, country and city.
The Urls should look like http://www.example.com/countryname/cityname.
Citynames are not unique in the world, e.g. there is a city called "Leipzig" in Germany and in the United States.

So i can have two URLs

- http://www.example.com/germany/leipzig
- http://www.example.com/united-states/leipzig

And the resolving of "leipzig" to the correct uid must respect the country part.

Is this possible with the currently provides enhancers/aspects?
If not, do you have any suggestion how to handle this cases?

```
routeEnhancers:
  MyWebsitePi1:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [1]
    extension: Website
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{country_slug}/{city_slug}'
        _controller: 'City::show'
        _arguments:
          country_slug: 'country'
          city_slug: 'city'
    defaultController: 'City::list'
    aspects:
      country_slug:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_mywebsite_domain_model_country'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
      city_slug:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_mywebsite_domain_model_city'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a combined slug field would be the best solution here. In your TCA code, you can configure the slug to be created from multiple db fields instead of just one:

```php
'slug' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:...',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'slug',
        'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
        'size' => 50,
        'eval' => 'uniqueInSite',
        'generatorOptions' => [
            'fields' => ['country', 'city'],
            'fieldSeparator' => '-',
            'prependSlash' => true,
            'prefixParentPageSlug' => true,
            'replacements' => [
                '/' => '',
            ],
        ]
    ],
],
```

Instead of `uniqueInSite` you can also use `uniqueInPid` (see [docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Slug.html)).
In the routing yml config, just read the slug field then with the `PersistedAliasMapper` and you are done. I have not yet tested to use a `/` as separator field, but `-` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael.

But sadly i need the slash in my real project, seo constant URLs andso ...

Also my real problem is a bit more complicated, having an static map between the two parameters (different offer types).

But i like your `uniqueInPid` suggestion, this i didn't know.